# Си подключение локальных библиотек без абсолютного пути

Tags: c, windows, mingw

У меня есть 3 файла, в следующей иерархии:

```
project:
    src
        lib.h
        lib.c
    main.c
```

Я нахожусь в директории `project`, файл `src\lib.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void say(const char *_Str);
```

Файл `src\lib.c`:

```
#include <lib.h>
void say(const char *_Str) {
    printf("%s", _Str);
}
```

Файл `main.c`:

```
#include <src\lib.h>
void main()
{
    sayHello("Hello!");
}
```

Чтоб нормально скомпилировать данную программу со своей библиотекой мне нужно указать АБСОЛЮТНЫЙ путь к файлам-заголовкам, то есть вместо `src\lib.h` указывать `C:\project\src\lib.h` и так далее .. + нужно компилировать вместе с `main.c` ещё и `lib.c`, -> `gcc.exe main.c C:\project\src\lib.c` подскажите как можно упростить себе задачу в этом плане. Или все же нужно указывать абсолютный путь к файлам-заголовкам и приписывать в `gcc` ещё 150 файлов `.c` если у меня будет большая библиотека с множеством `.h`, `.c` файлов.

Работаю под Windows x32-64

Comment: О какой "библиотеке" идет речь? Где здесь библиотека? (И `int main(void)`, а не `void main()`)

Answer (score 0):

В `#include` следует указывать нормальный слэш, даже в windows, ну и для своих файлов правильнее использовать include с кавычками:

```
#include "src/lib.h"
void main()
{
    sayHello("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: Проблему это не решило, все равно `C:\Users\C182~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccean2gn.o:main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `print'`

Comment: так библиотеку надо скомпилировать и указать её компоновщику

Comment: всё, спасибо, уже разобрался